How to literally translate this: 我每天放学回家总要经过这家书摊，都要进去看看?
印象中似乎没有什么押金，全凭信用。我每天放学回家总要经过这家书摊，都要进去看看。
This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 20. I need your help for literally translating this:
我(I)每天(every day)放学(finishing school)回家(returning home)总要(?)经过(to pass by or to pass through)这(this)家(classifier?)书摊(bookstall)，都要(?)进去(to get in)看看(to see)。
As you can see I don't understand the 总要 the 都要. Also, I am not sure whether 家 is classifier here.
Pleco dictionary says that 总要 means nevertheless, 总 according to wiktionary may mean always. Also, 要 as yao1 means to ask or to demand and as yao4 has many meanings like to want, to wish, will, if, should. Finally, the 都 as du1 means capital and as dou1 means all, both and a general emphatic point. And 家 in wiktionary has a classifier meaning.
So how to translate here these characters, and how are they pronounced?

In this case, 都 = 总, which means "always"; 要 means will.

我(I)每天(every day)放学(finishing school)回家(returning home)总要(always will)经过(to pass by or to pass through)这(this)家(classifier? "YES".)书摊(bookstall)，都要(always will)进去(to get in)看看(to see)。

My translation:
Every day after school on the way home, I always will pass this bookstand and always will get in it to have a look.

(我)总要经过 (I) always had to pass by
(每一次)都要进去: (every time I) always had to go in
印象中似乎没有什么押金，
I don't remember (having to pay a) deposit,
全凭信用。
everything relied on trust.
我每天放学回家(时)总要经过这家书摊，
Every day (when) school was over, on my way home, I always had to pass by that book stall,
(每一次)都要进去看看。
(every time I) always had to go in for a look.
